# Accessing Karma Configurations from a Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I was wondering if it was possible to access the settings defined within my karma.config.js file, and if so how?

I'm currently using a Grunt task runner to perform various tasks like building, linting, packaging, etc.  I'm also using Grunt to kick off the Karma test runner to run my Jasmine unit tests.  Furthermore, I'm pulling in the Jasmine-jQuery library so I can define and read in JSON and HTML fixtures from separate files that I setup earlier.

While I was writing some new tests, I noticed that I was redefining my fixtures base path in every test file.  So I decided to pull it out and put it into a global constant.

The problem I'm having is where I should define it.  Currently, I have a file named "testSettings.js" that I'm including in my karma configuration, where I define a configuration object and set it to window.testSettings.  Thats all well and good, but I think it would be better if I defined it within my karma configuration and then just referenced that from my tests.  But there doesn't look like a way to do this... or is there?

My library versions are:

```
"karma": "~0.12.32"
"karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5"
"karma-jasmine-jquery": "~0.1.1"
```

Comment: do you want to run your test cases when you run grunt ?

Comment: Yes and no.  Eventually these unit tests will be integrated with our continuous integration platform, in which case I'll call Karma directly.  But when the developer runs them from their dev environment, I'd like to keep it within the grunt environment, since all their other tasks are in grunt.  Thats why I felt that the constants should be in karma.config.js and not Gruntfile.js